# Workflow rule for "User" Standard object ErrorId 673358808-54985

Tags: workflow, standard-objects, package, workflowoutboundmessage

I am trying to upload a zip file with workflows, triggers and page layouts to my salesforce account. When ignoring the User object, my triggers and workflows successfully get deployed and works as expected.

The User.workflow file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Workflow xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <outboundMessages>
        <fullName>Elastica_User_OM</fullName>
        <apiVersion>25.0</apiVersion>
        <endpointUrl>https://abc.xyz.net/salesforce/elasticaco</endpointUrl>
        <fields>Id</fields>
        <fields>Username</fields>
        <fields>LastName</fields>
        <fields>FirstName</fields>
        <fields>Name</fields>
        <fields>CompanyName</fields>
        <fields>Division</fields>
        <fields>Department</fields>
        <fields>Title</fields>
        <fields>Street</fields>
        <fields>City</fields>
        <fields>State</fields>
        <fields>PostalCode</fields>
        <fields>Country</fields>
        <fields>Email</fields>
        <fields>Phone</fields>
        <fields>Fax</fields>
        <fields>MobilePhone</fields>
        <fields>Alias</fields>
        <fields>CommunityNickname</fields>
        <fields>IsActive</fields>
        <fields>TimeZoneSidKey</fields>
        <fields>UserRoleId</fields>
        <fields>LocaleSidKey</fields>
        <fields>ReceivesInfoEmails</fields>
        <fields>ReceivesAdminInfoEmails</fields>
        <fields>EmailEncodingKey</fields>
        <fields>ProfileId</fields>
        <fields>UserType</fields>
        <fields>LanguageLocaleKey</fields>
        <fields>EmployeeNumber</fields>
        <fields>DelegatedApproverId</fields>
        <fields>ManagerId</fields>
        <fields>LastLoginDate</fields>
        <fields>LastPasswordChangeDate</fields>
        <fields>CreatedDate</fields>
        <fields>CreatedById</fields>
        <fields>LastModifiedDate</fields>
        <fields>LastModifiedById</fields>
        <fields>SystemModstamp</fields>
        <fields>OfflineTrialExpirationDate</fields>
        <fields>OfflinePdaTrialExpirationDate</fields>
        <fields>UserPermissionsMarketingUser</fields>
        <fields>UserPermissionsOfflineUser</fields>
        <fields>UserPermissionsAvantgoUser</fields>
        <fields>UserPermissionsCallCenterAutoLogin</fields>
        <fields>UserPermissionsMobileUser</fields>
        <fields>UserPermissionsSFContentUser</fields>
        <fields>UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser</fields>
        <fields>UserPermissionsInteractionUser</fields>
        <fields>UserPermissionsSupportUser</fields>
        <fields>UserPermissionsSiteforceContributorUser</fields>
        <fields>UserPermissionsSiteforcePublisherUser</fields>
        <fields>UserPermissionsChatterAnswersUser</fields>
        <fields>ForecastEnabled</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesActivityRemindersPopup</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesEventRemindersCheckboxDefault</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesTaskRemindersCheckboxDefault</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesReminderSoundOff</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesDisableAllFeedsEmail</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesDisableFollowersEmail</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesDisableProfilePostEmail</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesDisableChangeCommentEmail</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesDisableLaterCommentEmail</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesDisProfPostCommentEmail</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesContentNoEmail</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesContentEmailAsAndWhen</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesApexPagesDeveloperMode</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesHideCSNGetChatterMobileTask</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesDisableMentionsPostEmail</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesDisMentionsCommentEmail</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesHideCSNDesktopTask</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesDisCommentAfterLikeEmail</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesDisableLikeEmail</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesDisableMessageEmail</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesOptOutOfTouch</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesDisableBookmarkEmail</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesDisableSharePostEmail</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesEnableAutoSubForFeeds</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesDisableFileShareNotificationsForApi</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesShowTitleToExternalUsers</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesShowManagerToExternalUsers</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesShowEmailToExternalUsers</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesShowWorkPhoneToExternalUsers</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesShowMobilePhoneToExternalUsers</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesShowFaxToExternalUsers</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesShowStreetAddressToExternalUsers</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesShowCityToExternalUsers</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesShowStateToExternalUsers</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesShowPostalCodeToExternalUsers</fields>
        <fields>UserPreferencesShowCountryToExternalUsers</fields>
        <fields>ContactId</fields>
        <fields>AccountId</fields>
        <fields>CallCenterId</fields>
        <fields>Extension</fields>
        <fields>FederationIdentifier</fields>
        <fields>AboutMe</fields>
        <fields>FullPhotoUrl</fields>
        <fields>SmallPhotoUrl</fields>
        <fields>DigestFrequency</fields>
        <fields>DefaultGroupNotificationFrequency</fields>
        <fields>Count__c</fields>
        <fields>Link_to_User__c</fields>
        <includeSessionId>true</includeSessionId>
        <integrationUser>sana.tahseen@69demo.com</integrationUser>
        <name>Elastica_User_OM</name>
        <protected>false</protected>
        <useDeadLetterQueue>false</useDeadLetterQueue>
    </outboundMessages>
    <rules>
        <fullName>Elastica_User_OM_rule</fullName>
        <actions>
            <name>Elastica_User_OM</name>
            <type>OutboundMessage</type>
        </actions>
        <active>true</active>
        <formula>ISNEW() || LastModifiedDate != PRIORVALUE(LastModifiedDate)</formula>
        <triggerType>onAllChanges</triggerType>
    </rules>
</Workflow>
```

But trying placing a workflow rule on the User standard object I always get the following error.

```
unpackaged/workflows/User.workflow(1, 131:An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 673358808-54985 (2111990722)
unpackaged/workflows/User.workflow(1, 4652:Field LastModifiedDate does not exist. Check spelling.

java.lang.Exception: The files were not successfully deployed
```

Comment: As a minimal test, can you see the LastModifiedDate field on the User object in the target org when using the same credentials that you are deploying with?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the ability to do User object workflow was only delivered last release (Winter 14) which means a likely cause of your error is the fact your metadata file is referencing API v 25. Try moving that up to the Winter 14 API number (29) and you should get your error Id disappearing.

If not then you may want to raise a case with support as they are the only people who can see the error log for those Ids.